# Doctrine Migrations in new DB setup

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

We're using Doctrine Migrations to keep the application DB in sync across versions. The app will be installed each time we get a new customer meaning a new DB for each installation.

Now, the new DB will have all DB changes in the migrations file in place but will try to execute the migration files as they are not registered in the migrations table.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Someone down voted my question... I would really like to know why so I can improve my question asking.

Comment: If you know what the last change is that the db has had, you can insert manualy all the version numbers or sync up one db that you keep as a base structure (which has all the versions in migration table) and then for iets client tun run the additional script to update the base db

Comment: @acrobat Thanks for your comment. I'm looking for some way to automatize this procedure to avoid human(me) failures :-)

Comment: Could you create the database schema in the new, empty database using the migrations?

Comment: @StuBez Hmm... that could be a solution... to have migrations for the whole creation of the DB instead of using doctrine:schema:create... Will give feedback about that idea as soon as I've tried out. Thanks!

Comment: @Michi I've used that approach in a previous project so it should work OK. I just wasn't sure how it might fit in with your workflow when installing a new instance of your app.

Comment: @StuBez I thinks it does... would you mind putting that up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I've successfully created a blank database schema just by using Doctrine migrations. I believe it's necessary to create the empty database first (`php app/console doctrine:database:create`) and then run the migrations task.

The only potential issue I can think of is that any base data that your app requires to function will either need to be in the migrations files or will need to be inserted separately.

As an aside, running the all the migrations in one go has picked up a couple of small errors that I'd missed when just executing one at a time.

Comment: For the "base data", you could use the [Doctrine Fixtures Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Comment: Maybe part of this solution is to load fixtures after running the migration scripts for the base database?

Answer (score 7):

Just after fresh install to fill current schema use this commands:

1. Create new empty chema of current version

   `./bin/console doctrine:schema:create`
2. Fill out the migration records with the current version (without actually run the migrations - schema already has current version after first command)

   `./bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --add --all`

This command adds records of the migrations and `doctrine:migrations:status` will show you that there is no migrations need for the current verions.

Thats all!

Comment: That sounds interesting and easy... it's not an issue right now for me anymore, but as soon as I have time I will look into it to see if that would work. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pick the very first migration class, copy it and rename with just one second before.

So, if your first class is `2016060712284351` you should create a new class called `2016060712284350`. This way it is executed just before the real migrations.

In this newly created class you setup your database creating all needed tables. This way, when you run migrations the first thing is done is to create the database with all the tables and then the real migrations are run.

Anyway I'm not sure this is the real way to proceed.
Migrations are needed to update the database schema, but if you are creating a new database for each user, each of the new users will have the new schema as per entities mapping. So a migration is not needed.

You need to run migration only for OLD USERS' DATABASES, am I right?